# How to make my ruby gem install native apt packages automatically during its installation?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, apt, gemfile

I'm building my own ruby gem, let's call it `my-gem`, which depends on some system package, for example `gpsbabel`. It expects to be able to call `gpsbabel` command using the shell.

On Ubuntu, before running `my-gem`, I have to make sure that `gpsbabel` is installed via `apt install gpsbabel`.

Is there a feature in rubygems, or maybe supplied by some other gems, that automates that? So that when I run `gem install my-gem`, it's ensured that `gpsbabel` is installed, and if not, it's installed automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain that what you're asking for is impossible, but I wouldn't recommend it anyway: `apt` would only be appropriate for Debian/Ubuntu systems, and ideally a gem would be cross-platform-friendly and thus not do anything platform-specific.

Granted, if you're making a gem for your own use only, then maybe it's viable? But I'd instead be looking at having a set-up script for the the relevant applications that installs the required packages before `bundle install`.